# Is it possible to create a child domain and migrate workstations to it in Windows 2012 AD?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a client that was initially setup as domain.com in Windows 2012 AD. For whatever reason they are migrating to a hosted Exchange server (instead of O365, which would be the better choice IMHO). The internal AD domain matches the external email domain, hence the problem. I am wondering how difficult it would be to create a new child domain (ad.domain.com) and move the workstations to that? There are only about 10 workstations and handful of GPOs etc. How much of a chore would this be? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Actually a good question on *how* to do this!